# How can I make a circle with bitten pieces in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, drawing

How can I make a circle with bitten pieces like this [image: glaze of donut]
I mean how to draw the pink cirlce in this case. Tnx

Comment: Huh? What bitten pieces? What have you tried so far so we know what you're stuck on?

Comment: Draw a Shape with the points then Boole the middle out with a Circle :)

Comment: This is a poor question. Please show us something you tried, do some research on the internet and come back with a specific question.

Comment: @Luciano does that mean that I should delete my question? I m just a new here. But the problem was solved anyway.

Comment: You can keep your question, since it has attracted some good answers anyway, but we're looking for questions that can be useful to the design community and not just tech support or basic tutorials. If you want to know more about the site, please read the [help]. You can also casually ping somebody on the [chat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Draw a circle
2. With the circle selected, choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig Zag`
3. Tick the `Smooth` option then adjust the sliders to create "bumps"
   [image]
   Click `OK` ----
   if you want evenly rounded ridges then stop here and proceed to step 7
4. (For less symmetrical bumps) -- Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Roughen`
5. Again, tick the `Smooth` option, tick the `Absolute` option and reduce the `Detail` down to 0, then play with the `Size` slider 
   to create an asymmetrical shape.

[image]

6. Click `OK`
7. Choose `Object > Expand Appearance`
8. Draw your center circle and position it where you want:
   [image]
9. Choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` and you'll have a hole in the
   middle of the shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, draw the Rough shape of it. Use the pencil tool to accomplish that.

[image: The shape]

After that draw a Circle for the cutout in the Middle:

[image: Red circle for the cutout]

Finally use the Pathfinder Tool to substract the Red Circle from the Black shape:

[image: Pathfinder]

[image: Final Piece]